# Display a list/set of strings vertically in in multiple columns

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts, jstl

I have a sorted Set of String and I need to display it using jsp/html.

How can I display it in the following format using JSTL or struts tags? This list in the display will grow sideways instead of top to bottom. I was thinking about having 25 rows and N number of columns(which increases as the size of the set increases).

```
AAB         CCD         FAA
ABA         CCE         FAB
ABB         CDE         FBB
BAA         DAA         FCC
BAB         DAB         FDD
BBB         DBA         FEE
CAA         DDD         FFF
CBA         EAA
CBB         EAB
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: That's great and all, but you'll need to form a question if you want help.  Ideally you would show us your approach and what is limiting you from implementing your solution.

Comment: @DMoses Thanks. I have changed my post into a question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you some psudo-code if you want.  You can transplate this into any language you want php, java's jstl, etc.

Let's say we want to produce : http://jsfiddle.net/vQyyB/

```
for (i = 0, i < strings.count, i++) {
    if (i % itemsPerColumn == 0) {
        if (i != 0) print "</div>" 
        print "<div class='container'>"
    }
    print "<div class='foo'>" + string[i] + "</div>"
}
```

If all you needed was a starting point, I hope that helps.  You can implement this using `<c:forEach>` if you want to use jstl.